# How can I store replaced values after filter() %>% mutate()?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm attempting to replace empty values in column z based on the values in column x.

I've used filter() to narrow down to the rows of importance, and apply mutate() afterwards, but the mutate values are not replaced in the original dataframe. I can store it as a new dataframe, but merging afterwards would be a considerable headaches as this is happening across dozens of conditionals.

make dummy data

```
xx <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c("a","","c"), z=c(5,5,""))

xx %>% filter(x == 3) %>% # filter to value of interest
  filter(z == "") %>% # filter to NA values to be replaced
 mutate(z = replace(z, z =="", 5) ) # mutate to replace NA value
```

if i do:

```
xx <- xx %>% filter(x == 3) %>% # filter to value of interest
  filter(z == "") %>% # filter to NA values to be replaced
  mutate(z = replace(z, z =="", 5) ) # mutate to replace NA value
```

then only the single row is stored...

I'm looking for a way to keep all of the other dataframe data but replace the mutated data.

Feels like it should be a quick fix, but been stuck on it for a while..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. Can you show your expected output for a slightly larger sample dataset, and include a clear set of "rules" for replacing missing values in column `z`?

Comment: Unfortunately `filter()` just doesn't work like this, it returns a new dataframe with all the filtered out rows deleted, with no connection to the original. Instead of `filter()`, you might want to look at using `mutate()` along with `ifelse()` or `case_when()`.

Comment: Maybe you just need `xx %>% 
 mutate(z = replace(z, z == "", 5))`

Comment: or `xx %>% mutate(z = replace(z, z =="" & x==3, 5))`

Comment: `""` and `NA` aren't the same. You say you're filtering for `NA` values but don't have any. There's only one row for which x = 3 and z = "", so I don't know what you expect to get after filtering both times

Comment: This is a place where `data.table`'s syntax really shines. `setdt(xx); xx[x == 3 & z == "", z := 5]` would do what you are looking for. (Well, in either case you should probably convert your `z` column to a numeric first)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `ifelse()` statement within `dplyr::mutate()`.

```r
df <- data.frame(x=sample(1:10,100,T),
                 y=sample(c(NA,1:5),100,T))

df %>% mutate(y=ifelse(is.na(y),x,y))

   x y
1  7 7
2 10 3
3  7 1
4  7 1
5 10 4
6  3 3
...
```

Comment: Thanks @marius for the filter function clarification.    @kstew the embedded ifelse did the trick.   a variant of `xx %>% mutate(z=ifelse(x==3 & z=="",6,z))` did the trick.